# Developing QGIS Python plugins using Jupyter?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, references, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to run PYQGIS commands using Jupyter notebook and, if so, is there any documentation to develop QGIS plugins using Jupyter?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Ipython console(A kernel for Jupyter) for QGIS as a plugin, which you can add from QGIS official plugin repository or download from Github and copy to the plugin folder in QGIS.

> https://github.com/elpaso/qgis-ipythonconsole